# Changing name of application file (.C file)

Tags: c++, linux, build, projects-and-solutions

I changed the name of an modified application to seperate it from the basic application. Lets say the .C file of the old application is "OldApplication.C" and of the new modified one is "NewApplication.C" Unfortunately, when trying to start the new modified application in terminal by typing "NewApplication" I get:

```
NewApplication: command not found
```

Two Question:

1. How can I make my new application executeable?
2. Can someone give me a brief overview about the files of a project/application and their functions?

greetings, streight

Comment: Did you run `make clean`?

Comment: What build system do you use?

Comment: @Vitaly Isaev: I m "using" the gnu compiler. The build command is "wmake".

Answer (score 1):

The mistake of this kind

> make: *** No rule to make target `OldApplication.dep', needed by`Make/linuxGccDPOpt/dependencies'.  Stop.

often occurs in situation when the Makefile ceases to comply with the structure of the whole project.

In your case make script obviously trying to find the file that was renamed by you and therefore it fails with en error. I think that you should explore the structure of your Makefile and replace all the changed file names with its new versions.

Also you say the you are refused to launch your new executable, but what else could be expected since the project was not compiled?

Comment: Ok, you are right I forgot to change the name in one file and the build process is working fine now. I also edited my question. However, i still can`t execute the program.

Comment: @Streight, did the desired executable appeared in the build directory? Is it really executable? Call `file <your_program>` to be sure that it is really ELF binary formatted executable file. And which command do you use to start your programm?

Comment: I didn t try to create an executable, instead I tried to run my program in another folder where all the required files to ru n the program are. When I execute file `NewApplication.C` I get `NewApplication.C: ASCII English text`. I tried to run my program with "NewApplication".

Comment: @Streight, you cannot execute `NewApplication.C` since that is a source file. It is not the binary program that you have previously built.

Comment: So how can I execute the "NewApplication"? In `NewApplication.C` is the main method of my program...

Comment: If you have done everything write, the binary `NewApplication` should appear in builddir, and you can execute with a shell command `./NewApplication`

Comment: When I build the project I just get 3 warnings (these are not relevant) and the file `NewApplication.dep` is created. However, I tried now using `NewApplication`, `./NewApplication` and `./PathTo/NewApplication`, but always getting command not found...